# "Category 6a is particularly resistant to interference from older Ethernet signaling..."

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm going through "Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook", 5th edition. In chapter 14, "Physical networking" in the section on UTP cabling, it says:

> Category 6a is the cable of choice for new installations because it is particularly resistant to interference from older Ethernet signaling standards (e.g. 10BASE-T), a problem that has plagued some Category 5/5e installations.

What does this mean? That a cable with 10BASE-T running on it will project heavy interference on nearby Cat5 cables, but Cat6-es will be just fine? Is there any reading available on the Internet on this issue? I simply want to make sure I got it right (English is not my first language). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you are in an environment with heavy interference cat6e will work better then earlier standards - but not that they will work fine.

Google CAT6e vs CAT5E - for example this link describes the differences - https://www.diffen.com/difference/Cat5e_vs_Cat6